# How to assign mutiple keys via the value of variables for an javascript object literal

Tags: javascript

I wonder if it's possible to have an object like a multidimensional array?
What I want is something like:

```
lines[first][first first]= "value key key"        


    lines          =       {};
    key            =       "first";
    key_key        =       "first first";
    lines[key]     =       "value key ";
    lines[key][key_key]=   "value key key "

    console.log(lines);
```

Output:
can't convert undefined to object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lines[key]` is a string value. It should be an Object. Like this:

```
lines              = {};
key                = "first";
key_key            = "first first";
lines[key]         = {};
lines[key][key_key]= "value key key ";
//=> lines.first['first first'] now is 'value key key'
```

**OR**

```
lines              = {};
key                = "first";
key_key            = "first first";
lines[key]         = new String("value key ");
lines[key][key_key]= "value key key ";
//=> lines.first['first first'] still is 'value key key', 
//   but now it's a custom property of a String Object
```